# AngularJS ngChecked with ngDisabled not working

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS framework, and I have 2 checkbox fields: when the first is false the second is disabled, the data are saved on the server as JSON and when I click edit it recives and fill the data.

What I want to do is when I have a data in the second field I want the first field to be checked and and the second field not disabled.
This is my code:

```
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <label class="checkbox i-checks col-lg-offset-1 pull-right"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="excelLaunchCheck" ng-checked="defobj.data.excelLaunch == true"><i></i></label>
                </td>
                <td>Excel</td>
                <td>Launch</td>
                <td>
                    <label class="checkbox i-checks col-lg-offset-1"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="defobj.data.excelLaunch" ng-disabled="!excelLaunchCheck"><i></i></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

now when I have data in the second field, the first field is checked, but the second field is still disabled, how do I enable it?

Comment: You have your `ng-model` and `ng-checked` / `ng-disabled` mixed up.

Comment: when someone click on edit , it enters this html , so it shows him what his previous choices were and are able to change them . so want to make so , that if by previous time he already selected something , it wont be set as disabled !!

Comment: Not quite sure what you want. Put it on JSFiddle or Plunker.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your structure of mappings, but try something like this :

```
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="checkbox i-checks col-lg-offset-1 pull-right"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="excelLaunchCheck" ng-checked="defobj.data.excelLaunch == true"><i></i></label>
            </td>
            <td>Excel</td>
            <td>Launch</td>
            <td>
                <label class="checkbox i-checks col-lg-offset-1"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="excelLaunchCheck" ng-disabled="defobj.data.excelLaunch == false"><i></i></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: thx , but that is not good , i need ng-model to be defobj.data.excelLaunch because thats how i recieve the data from the server , and i want it to be filled in

Comment: so the question is what is the difference between checked and disabled checkbox'es, if one works the second should be done similarly.

Comment: in this example i have checkbox , but i have others that are text so i wanna check if != null , but the idea is that the first checkbox is checked but the secondcheck box is still disabled , and i wanna enable it

Comment: So control it with different variable, if it is different functionality that you need to achieve, when you need to make it enabled, change it accordingly in controller.